# EOF not detected using scanf

Tags: c, io, eof, ansi-c

I created a function which should read some integers from file to an array. The function should also catch cases where there aren't enough integers to fill the array, and terminate (i.e. EOF reached while filling the array).

My problem: the function doesn't seem to catch the eof case, with `scanf` reusing already scanned values. So, for example, the input `12 22` for a size 4 array will fill the array as `12 22 22 22`.

```c
int fillArray(int* array, int size) {
    int temp = 0, i;

    for (i = 0; i<size; ++i) {
        if(!scanf("%d", &temp) || !(temp > 0)) {
            if(feof(stdin)) {
                printf("Error: not enough numbers"); /* Should be EOF */
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Error: positive numbers only");
            return 1;
        } else {
            heapArray[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that after the second iteration, `scanf` should return `0` after a conversion failure, entering into the larger `if` block. At that point `feof(stdin)` should be true, terminating the function and printing the error message.

However, it seems the conversion failure for `scanf` doesn't happen.

Comment: When you hit the end of the file, scanf returns EOF.  `!EOF` evaluates to false, so ...

Comment: You aren't checking `fscanf` return properly for EOF. So you can't say it's not detected. See the [manual page for `fscanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). `if(feof(stdin))` is definitely not going to work.